# LWJGL allow negative mouse coordinates (outside window)

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm trying to get the mouse coordinates with LWJGL [Mouse](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html) class. By default, LWJGL clamps the values to [0, width] and [0, height], so the coordinates are always inside the window, even when the mouse has gone outside it.

I've tried setting the [setClipMouseCoordinatesToWindow](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html#setClipMouseCoordinatesToWindow%28boolean%29) to false, but nothing happened; the mouse is still clipped to the window. I first tried to set it once to false, during initialization, and then each time I'd call Mouse.getX() or getY(). Neither worked. I know there is a property to be set, but it didn't work either, and it seems to have been deprecated too.

I only call the mouse functions inside my update method (the one Slick2D provides). I don't know what I'm doing wrong... I'm not calling Mouse.poll() manually, I assume Slick2D takes care of that, but I did try to call it manually just in case, but it didn't work anyway.

Edit: I also tried `System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.allowNegativeMouseCoords", "true");` but it did not work either, even though it seems to be exactly what I needed.

Edit: It seems this works if I am holding the mouse button down, but does not work otherwise because of some Windows limitation. [Source](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4291.msg23798#msg23798)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.allowNegativeMouseCoords", "true");`

Comment: I also tried this, both in my main method, and every time I tested the mouse position, just to be sure, but neither worked. This property is exactly what I needed, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Maybe your LWJGL is too old? You set the property first thing in the main method?

Comment: I'm using 2.8.5, the latest stable release as of now (released 2012-11-04). Yes, I tried it in several places, one of which the first thing of the main method. Maybe I'll try the LWJGL nightly build when I have time.

Comment: Well, it seems that property works only when the mouse is being pressed. When I tried, I was getting negative mouse coords just fine. Looks like Windows won't give LWJGL the coordinates if the mouse simply leaves the window, so it's not a problem of LWJGL itself.
Either way, thank you for your answer.